# How to iterate through unordered list using only classname

Tags: javascript

```
<ul class="block-content first last odd">
<li class="item first">First</li>
<li class="item">Second</li>
<li class="item last">Third</li>
</ul>
<div class="add-to-cart">
<button type ="button" title="Add To Cart">
</div>
```

can anyone tell me how to check in unordered list how to check perticular list item exist and using only class name and if perticular list item is not then how we can check and in javascript

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about: 1) **What you want to happen** 2) **What currently happens** 3) **What you have tried.**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LCT6h/61/

Comment: here actually i am searching for perticular item in list even if perticular item is not present still it say found what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check for a list item by class name:

```
if($("ul.block-content > li.last").length == 0) alert("Not found.");
```

Comment: plz tell me how to check in javascript

Comment: how to check perticular list item is present using javascript

Comment: To check that the item is present, just change == to > i.e. `if($("ul.block-content > li.last").length > 0) alert("Found.");`

Comment: can i check directly var first = document.getElementsByClassName('item first');if(first.length > 0)

Comment: no if second item is not present but still shows presend why just check http://jsfiddle.net/3uxRY/5/

Comment: All your li have class item

Comment: yes... you said you want to search by class, so either add another class to the li or change the method

Comment: can you suggest me how to search using javascript

Comment: can you give me a better idea of what exactly you want to search for?

Comment: my site http://efg.gostorego.com/occasion/birthday/cotton-candy.html in this choose extra is there below Add to Cart Button is ther i have to move it according to number of items in Choose extra and i am searching how many items are there if one i am setting some marginTop for Add to cart buttom please check this site page then only you'll understand.Thanks in Advance

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to know how many li elements are attached to the ul: `document.getElementsByClassName("block-content first last odd")[0].children.length`. You would probably be better off to give the ul an id (i.e. "choose-extra") and then use `document.getElementById("choose-extra").children.length`.

Comment: @ic3b3rg There's no need for you to say anything, the system prompts users to accept answers and to vote.  Don't do it again, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

This will check if the `Third` LI exists:

```
if ($(".block-content .li:contains('Third')").length === 0) {
    alert("Third not found");
}
```

Comment: A few things: 'block-content' is a class name, not an id; request was to check by class name, not by text; you're missing the closing quote in your selector

Comment: Fixed first and third things, I have a hard time parsing the question to know for sure if the second is what he wants. He can let us know by accepting my answer or yours.